# Python: Act upon (sub)list depending on elements

Tags: python, list, sublist

[I'm starting out with python; sorry if the following is dumb, but I've wrapped my head around this all day long and feel that I won't be able to solve this myself.]

I've got a list like:

```
list = [['a', 'A', '10.0.0.2'], ['a', 'TXT', '1'], ['a', 'TXT', '2'], ['b', 'A', '10.10.10.10'], ['c', 'A', '10.0.0.3'], ['c', 'TXT', '3'], ['c', 'TXT', '4']]
```

This example shows the list with seven sublists, but there could be n.

What I would like to achieve: Each unique `list[i][0]` (in this case, 'a', 'b', 'c') should have 'A' and 'TXT' in the corresponding sublists, so in this example, keep all `list[i][0] == 'a'` and `list[i][0] == 'c'`, delete all occurrences of `list[i][0] == 'b'`.

I've tried various stuff to accomplish this, but nothing to show actually, because I'm missing an idea, how to do this.

What I've did:

Get unique `list[i][0]`:

`names = [list[i][0] for i in range(len(list))]`

`names_unique = list(set(names))`

But then...how to proceed? I guess, something like `for ... in ...` should do the trick? Could anybody shed some light on this? Would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit 1:** Sorry for not being clear: 'a', 'b' and 'c' are just arbitrary values. I don't know these in advance, it's output of a dns zone transfer. I would like to keep all hostnames (here: 'a', 'b', 'c') which got associated A and TXT records, and drop these without TXT. I can't hardcode any names like 'a', b' or 'c', because these change; instead, I'm trying to come up with code which does what I've described here.

Desired output:

```
list = [['a', 'A', '10.0.0.2'], ['a', 'TXT', '1'], ['a', 'TXT', '2'], ['c', 'A', '10.0.0.3'], ['c', 'TXT', '3'], ['c', 'TXT', '4']]
```

Comment: Unclear what you are attempting to accomplish, please give sample input and output.

Comment: Edited to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
'define a function that checks if a key is valid or not'
def isValid(key, l):
    return all(_ in (x[1] for x in filter(lambda x:x[0] == key,l)) for _ in ['TXT','A'])

keys = list(set(x[0] for x in l))
keysValid = []
for key in keys: 
    if isValid(key, l): keysValid.append(key)

filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] in keysValid, l))
```

all this does is get all possible keys, then add all valid keys into a new list. It then uses `filter` on the original list to check if the key is in the valid key list.

This is an ugly one liner that you could also use:

```
>>> l = [['a', 'A', '10.0.0.2'], ['a', 'TXT', '1'], ['a', 'TXT', '2'], ['b', 'A', '10.10.10.10'], ['c', 'A', '10.0.0.3'], ['c', 'TXT', '3'], ['c', 'TXT', '4']]
>>> #this monstrosity right here
>>> u = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] in filter(lambda key: all(_ in (x[1] for x in filter(lambda x:x[0] == key,l)) for _ in ['TXT','A']),set(li[0] for li in l)),l))
>>> u
[['a', 'A', '10.0.0.2'], ['a', 'TXT', '1'], ['a', 'TXT', '2'], ['c', 'A', '10.0.0.3'], ['c', 'TXT', '3'], ['c', 'TXT', '4']]
```

MAJOR NOTE: this is sort of unrelated to your original question but do not use `list` as a variable name. This will disallow any call to python's cast to list function `list()` which is useful when you are using `filter()/set()` because they return `filter/set objects` rather than `list`.

Comment: @R Nar: Brilliant! Thanks so much, works as expected! I did a small syntax  fix as well and added a missing ")". Regarding your MAJOR NOTE: Yeah, thanks, I'm fully aware of this, in my code the list is named differently. Just typed it here directly instead of using copy/paste, didn't thought about this, so thanks for the hint.

Comment: @gf_ thanks for the edit, i didn't actually check that first code block, so thank you for doing that

Answer (score 1):

You could try using filter and a lambda expression. For example:

```
acceptable_elements = ['a','b']
filtered_list = filter(lambda sublist: (sublist[0] in acceptable_elements), my_list)
```

This will check all elements of the list, and won't alter your original list. I can't precisely tell from your example whether or not you want to check just in the first position or in the entire list, if you want to check for the existence of elements within the entire list:

```
acceptable_elements = ['a','b']
filtered_list = filter(lambda sublist: any([c in acceptable_elements for c in sublist]), my_list)
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm not able to hardcode any values like 'a' and 'b'. I've edited my question to make this more clear.

Comment: But you're still testing for inclusion in the sublist right?

Comment: It might be more clear to gf_ if you pulled ['a', 'b'] out into a separate variable, since there's nothing 'hard coded' about it.

Comment: Yeah, maybe 'hardcoded' wasn't correct, depends I think what one means with that. Still I think, that this test wouldn't be that helpful, because it doesn't test for 'A' and 'TXT' per hostname ('a', 'b', 'c'). But maybe it's obvious and I'm just overlooking it.

Comment: Oh wait, so you want to see if there's an A or a TXT in the second position?

Comment: @Galen Harrison: Thanks for your edit and clarification, I understand this better now, and your code sort of works. However, it tests for 'a' or 'b', which, used on my example, outputs the hostnames 'a', 'b' and 'c', which is wrong, because the output should be limited to 'a' and 'c'; each hostname should have 'a' and 'b' included / associated. [Maybe using 'a'  and 'b' for different things is not that clear...] Any hint for this last problem as well? (Is my explanation clear, do you understand, what I'm trying to accomplish?)